# R: create new column with name coming from variable

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns and would like to add a new column and name it according to a previous variable. For example:

```
df <- data.frame("A" = c(1, 2, 3, 4), "B" = c("a", "c", "d", "b"))
Variable <- "C"
```

This is part of a function where the variable will be changing and rather than each time specifying:

```
df$C <- NA
```

I would like a one line that will take the "Variable" to name the additional column

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try `[` instead of `$`:

```
> df[, Variable] <- NA
> df
  A B  C
1 1 a NA
2 2 c NA
3 3 d NA
4 4 b NA
```

Comment: Or `df[[Variable]] <- NA`

Comment: If you are attempting to use a variable that is an integer, you will need to include `as.character` to make this work:
`df[, as.character(Variable)] <- NA`
Otherwise, you will get an error saying:
`new columns would leave holes after existing columns`

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a data.frame name also taken in a variable this might be helpful.

```
df <- data.frame("A" = c(1, 2, 3, 4), "B" = c("a", "c", "d", "b") )
Variable<-"C"
dfname<-"df"
df<-within ( assign(dfname  , get(dfname) ),
             assign(Variable, NA          )
           )
```